# What is considered good/acceptable grade in Germany?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, research-undergraduate, germany

Currently, I have graduated my Bs degree in Computer Science with 3.04 GPA out of 4.00. When I translate my GPA to German grading system, it shows me 2.44, if I consider the lowest passing grade as 2.00, or 2.23 if I take the lowest passing grade as 1.66. Generally, I see that 2.44.-2.23 grade is considered "gut", but is it enough for applying in German Ms in Computer Science? Have I still any good chances? If I even will not apply to the TU9 universities.

Comment: Quick comment: That also depends on which university awarded your degree. UC Berkeley or MIT? All universities will welcome you, pretty much regardless of your GPA. Regional for-profit Asian university? Will be difficult at the better CS places, such as Saarland University.

Comment: The TU9 do not generally have higher admission standards than other German universities. In fact the TU9 have wasted a lot of their high standards in teaching during the years of the "Exzellenzinitiative", trying to attract hot shot researchers (with very little success), and secure additional funding for them. All German universities are good, but all of them have departments where you don't want to go.

Comment: By Bs degree, do you mean Bachelor of Science degree (commonly abbreviated BS or B.S.)?

Comment: yes, bachelor of science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Anja's answer is fine, let me do a more general one which doesn't focus on the grades in particular:

> if I consider the lowest passing grade as 2.00,

> if I take the lowest passing grade as 1.66.

To take the TUM (TU München, part of TU9) as an example, they usually do not have a point-blank minimum grade for most curricula. Most importantly, they have no waiting lists where even with a lower grade you can rise up by waiting longer, which also means you are not exactly competing against other students so much. This is probably more common in topics like medicine (though I don't know how *those* handle it these days).

TUM will take your grades, as well as a veritable plethora of other aspects (very much importance will probably be placed on your language skills and motivation), mush them all together, and try to find out how likely it is that you will be able to successfully finish the curriculum, to avoid waisting your and their time.

> enough for applying in German Ms in Computer Science?

There is no concept of "enough" in German CS studies. It really depends on all your circumstances together.

> Have I still any good chances?

Not even the unis themselves give an indication what marks or other aspects increase or decrease your chances since it is just too complex. If you fail to be accepted, that will probably be more because your application documents, your language skills, your explanation of why you want to study in Germany and so on were considered lacking, and not so much because there were loads of "better" students.

> If I even will not apply to the TU9 universities.

You should most definitely apply at the uni(s) which seem most attractive to you. Choices like the city where you will be living (including the price range of housing, and your personal priorities about public life and so on) should probably be high on your list.

While the TU9 use terms like "excellence" and such, there really is not that much of elitism in the public universities in Germany (certainly not in the technical ones), compared to how it is for other well-known unis (i.e., Oxford, MIT, etc.). If a TU9 uni ticks all your checkboxes, by all means apply there. It is online and hence relatively effortless compared to everything else that lies in your future.

Some sources, again for TUM by way of an example. Presumably the other unis will be more or less the same, as much of this is regulated nation-wide, not for specific unis:

- [TUM's CS Master homepage](https://www.tum.de/studium/studienangebot/detail/informatik-master-of-science-msc)
- [Their FAQ](https://www.tum.de/studium/hilfe-und-beratung/faq#c69861)
- [anabin](https://anabin.kmk.org/kurzanleitung/ich-moechte-feststellen-wie-mein-auslaendischer-hochschulabschluss-in-deutschland-bewertet-wird.html) (info on how foreign degrees are interpreted in Germany)
- [Zulassungsdatenbank](https://www.daad.de/de/in-deutschland-studieren/voraussetzungen/zulassungsdatenbank/?ad-layer=4&ad-layerId=4553) (the same, with a form where you can enter your own info)

Answer (score 26):

As someone with a background in Computer Science from Germany, I think it's important to understand how the German university system evaluates international grades, especially when considering applications for Master's programs. The German grading system is quite different from the GPA system used in many other countries. It ranges from 1.0 (very good) to 5.0 (fail), with a passing grade typically being 4.0 or better.

When translating your GPA to the German system, the resulting grades of 2.44 or 2.23, depending on the conversion method used, indeed fall within the "gut" (good) range. In Germany, grades are generally classified as follows: "sehr gut" (very good) for grades between 1.0 and 1.5, "gut" (good) for grades between 1.6 and 2.5, "befriedigend" (satisfactory) for grades between 2.6 and 3.5, and "ausreichend" (sufficient) for grades between 3.6 and 4.0.

For Master's programs in Computer Science, especially outside the TU9 group of leading technical universities in Germany, your grade would likely be considered competitive. The TU9 universities are known for their high standards and might have stricter admission criteria, but even then, your academic background will not solely determine your admission chances. Universities also consider other factors such as your statement of purpose, letters of recommendation, research experience, and any relevant work experience.

It's also worth noting that some universities and specific programs may have their own grading conversion scales or may consider additional factors beyond just the numerical grade. Therefore, while your grades are an important part of your application, they are not the only aspect that admissions committees will evaluate.

Given your GPA and assuming you have a strong overall application, you should still have good chances of being admitted to a Master's program in Computer Science in Germany, particularly if you apply to a range of universities including but not limited to the TU9. It's also beneficial to directly contact the admissions offices of the programs you're interested in to get specific advice and to understand how your international GPA will be evaluated in the context of their requirements.